# AWS SAM - local api call to return version 2 of the event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-http-api

I am using AWS SAM to test my Api gateway and lambdas locally.
When executing `sam local start-api` and calling a lambda, I'd like the `event` to be of [version 2.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html#2.0) format instead of version 1.

I am using CDK `HttpApi` construct from `@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2` hence there is now inconsistency between my local testing and what's deployed.

I am new to Sam config, my *template.yml* file is:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:
  MyFunction:
  Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
  Properties:
    Handler: index.handler
    Runtime: nodejs14.x
    CodeUri: .output/healthz
    Timeout: 10
    Events:
      ApiEvent:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /health
          Method: GET
Globals:
 HttpApi:
    CorsConfiguration:
    AllowOrigin: "'http://localhost:3000'"
    AllowMethods: "'POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT'"
    AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
```

I've tried various setups (Api, HttpApi) using those [AWS Docs for SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-httpapi.html) but always manage to get only version 1 event.

Can you point me to what I am doing wrong or how to specify the version?

Answer (score 1):

I found the resolution [in this post](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2678).
It is necessary to specify `PayloadFormatVersion: "2.0"` (value as string) in the configuration of HttpApi.

Example yml:

```
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      CodeUri: .output/healthz
      Timeout: 10
      Events:
        ApiEvent:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            PayloadFormatVersion: "2.0"
            Path: /health
            Method: GET
            Auth:
              Authorizer: NONE
```